# Truffle: how to setup some smart contract's attributes before writing test

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

For example I have a smart contract with 2 attributes:

```
contract SimpleSmartContract {
    uint256 currentPrices;
    mapping(uint8 => uint256) public priceIncrements;
}
```

When I write test, I want to test some situations (depends on the state of attributes). My question is: How can I setup data for those variables before running tests. (i.e: set currentPrices to 100, and set up map to some data before).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick that I use is to create a test contract that inherit from my contract. I create a method that will setup the correct values

```
contract SimpleSmartContractTest is SimpleSmartContract {
    function setup() public {
        currentPrices = 1234;
        priceIncrements[1] = 100;
        priceIncrements[2] = 110;
        priceIncrements[3] = 120;
    }
}
```

Now I when running my test I create an instance of `SimpleSmartContractTest` but because it inherit from `SimpleSmartContract` all methods are available.

```
const SimpleSmartContractTest = artifacts.require('SimpleSmartContractTest');

contract('SimpleSmartContract', (accounts) => {
    let simpleSmartContract;
    before(async () => {
        simpleSmartContract = await SimpleSmartContractTest.new(constructorParams..)
        await simpleSmartContract.setup(setupParams..)
    })
    it('Transfer', async () => {
        // Here test like it was SimpleSmartContract
        const result = await simpleSmartContract.transfer(accounts[1], 100, 
            { from: accounts[0] })
        assert.equal(result.logs[0].event, 'Transfer', 'Transfer should succeed')
    })
})
```

Comment: nice trick. I can make some "helper" method in this contract also. :D I have a scenario that I want to assert some state of smart contract, ie: balance[address]. How can you achieve this ? By writing helper method on mock contract also ? thanks.

Comment: @hqt Since it is a contract you can add more functions. The only issue might be that you cannot access `private` functions nor variables in the base contract. But otherwise you can access `internal` and `public` functions.